# Получение результата от асинхронного запроса

Tags: javascript, react-native

React Native, пробую использовать БД SQlite, хочу при открытие приложения на телефоне подгружать из SQlite в хук как начальный стейт всю базу раннее сохранённых данных, в моём случае приложение Todo List.
Проблема в том, что я не могу получить данные из БД, зная что запрос асинхронный с помощью
async/await & promise, имею следующий код.

```
    async function getData() {
        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.transaction(tx => {
                tx.executeSql(
                    'SELECT * FROM test', [],
                    (_, {rows}) =>
                        resolve(rows));
            },error => {
                reject(error);
            });
        })
    }
    
    let result = getData().then(data => result = data);
    console.log(result)
```

Console.log выводит следующее

```
 Promise {
      "_U": 0,
      "_V": 0,
      "_W": null,
      "_X": null,
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: `let result = await getData()`

Comment: Разве можно сделать это вне функции async?

Comment: Иногда можно https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await

Comment: Но в общем случае нет, так что см. дубликат. Короткий ответ — синхронно нельзя. Совсем нельзя. Никак нельзя.

Comment: Тогда какие у меня варианты? Мне нужно при открытие приложения получить весь список из БД.

Comment: Переключить голову на асинхонные рельсы. Обычно приложения при открытии сплешскрин показывают, а сами что-то там втихаря делают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я изучил ещё много информации по этой теме и решил эту проблему самостоятельно, оставлю свой код тут, возможно кому-то будет полезен.

```
function getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                'SELECT * FROM test', [],
                (_, {rows}) =>
                    resolve((rows._array)));
        }, error => {
            reject(error);
        });

    })
}

useEffect(() => {
        getData().then(data => setTodos(data))
    }, []);

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
```

В итоге благодаря useEffect приложение единожды получает данные из Promise и сохраняет его в useState, без конфликтов при дальнейшем использовании.